# Facebook App for Insights Data Only Needs Login Review

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook app that I use only for retrieving insights data on my pages programatically. This means the app must have "manage_pages" permission, which puts it in scope for the new Login Review for Facebook Graph API v2.0. My question: is this something that I need to go through?  My app isn't public facing and is only used internally and so the process doesn't seem to fit its use.  Is there another approach to retrieving insights data for my pages via the API that doesn't involve an app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an "eternal" Page Access Token as outlined here:

- http://blog.lwolf.org/blog/2014/06/16/obtaining-never-expiring-access-token-to-post-on-facebook-page/

Page Access Token docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I still need an app in order to get the eternal token.  This is what I'm doing now.

Comment: No, you don't need your app all the time, only to exchange the short-lived Access Token to the long-lived one. The other stuff can be done via Graph Explorer. You don't need the Login Review if you're using an admin/developer/tester of the respective app.

Comment: That makes sense.  Unfortunately, the user that has the page permissions  (business user) is different from the user that owns the app (me).  I'll have to see if I can gain access to the page, or add the business user onto my app.  Thanks for the info.