# Do I need to update my access tokens every 60 days?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I simply want to list all posts of an (public) facebook page.

I've generated an access token using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/).

I switched to my app and clicked on "Get Page Access Token" and got a access token that lasts for 2 hours. And then I opened the following URL
`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=(1)&client_secret=(2)&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=(3)` and got an access token that now last for 60 days.

When I'm trying to fetch the raw posts with the following lines, I now get a result.

```
$appID = 'MY_APP_ID';
$appSecret = 'MY_APP_SECRED';
$accessToken = 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN';
$pageID = 'MY_PAGE_ID';

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
            'app_id'                => $appID,
            'app_secret'            => $appSecret,
            'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5'
        ]);
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($accessToken);

$response = $fb->get('/' . $pageID. '/posts');
$posts = $response->getDecodedBody()['data'];
var_dump($posts); // returns stuff that is looking good to me
```

Do I need to refresh the access token every 60 days or will it refresh automatically? If not, how can I refresh the token programmatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook App for Insights Data Only Needs Login Review](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30054314/facebook-app-for-insights-data-only-needs-login-review)

Comment: @Tobi : This is not working for me. I've done the thing described in the linked blog, but all my tokens that are listed after typing `me/accounts/` will expire in 1 hour.